# Swiper height auto resize

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

I have added swiper code in [REMOVED].

my code like here

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <!--First Slide-->
      <div class="swiper-slide" id="swiper-slide"> 
            <div class="content-slide">
                content1
            </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <!--Second Slide-->
      <div class="swiper-slide" id="swiper-slide"> 
            <div class="content-slide">
                content1
            </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

They have blank space.

[Please see image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9A5Jt.png)

I want to remove this space.

Comment: Try To Create Fiddle.net

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Update:**

As passatgt mentioned in the comments for newer versions `calculateHeight` is replaced with `autoHeight`, [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/ee083a5c7da9cc05d05840fefc026cf747386195/demos/390-autoheight.html) you can find an example:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  autoHeight: true, //enable auto height
  spaceBetween: 20,
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});
```

---

Add `calculateHeight:true` to swiper definition.

```
 var tabsSwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    speed:300,
    calculateHeight:true,
    onSlideChangeStart: function(){
      $(".tabs li").removeClass('active')
      $(".tabs li").eq(tabsSwiper.activeIndex).addClass('active')  
    }
  })
```

Comment: For newer swiper versions, you need to use autoHeight: true

Comment: The autoHeight fixed a lot of wierd configs haha! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it like this

//import these 2 for pagination css

import 'swiper/css';

import 'swiper/css/pagination';

```
 <Swiper
                autoHeight={true}
                spaceBetween={30}
                pagination={{
                    clickable: true
                }}
                direction={'horizontal'}
                mousewheel={{ forceToAxis: true }}
                modules={[Pagination, Mousewheel]}
                className={'mySwiper'}
            >
                {images?.map((img, index) => (
                    <SwiperSlide key={index}>
                        <div key={index}>
                            <img src={img} className="h-auto w-[-webkit-fill-available] " />
                        </div>
                    </SwiperSlide>
                ))}
            </Swiper>
```

//css file

```
.mySwiper > div:nth-child(1) {
    margin-bottom: 10%;
}
```